# Using handler.postDelayed with "for"

Tags: android, for-loop, android-handler

Basically, I am trying to do something more complicated than that, but this is my problem:

When using handler.postDelayed inside a for loop, there's delay only on the first time, and I wait the delay to kick in every time the for loop repeats:

For example, in this case:

```
    for(int z=0; z<4; z++) {
        final int finalZ = z;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(play.this, "z:" + finalZ, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
```

I will get:

- Waiting 5 seconds.
- z:0
- z:1
- z:2
- z:3

What I **want** to get:

- Waiting 5 seconds.
- z:0
- Waiting 5 seconds.
- z:1
- Waiting 5 seconds.
- z:2
- Waiting 5 seconds.
- z:3

I was told not to use Thread.sleep() because it can cause various issues (I didn't quite understand them as I am new to android studio). I am using this in a certain activity (not my Main_Activity).

I am basically trying to change an image's color ever 0.5 seconds or so (more complications go into that, but that's the main idea). Will Thread.sleep() be better?

**EDIT:** Okay, so thanks to @tynn & @pskink I got this to work (see their answers). But now, another problem came up following this.

If, for example, I will run the **exact** same code after that, they will both run at the same time, and not one after another, how can i make the second "for" start only after the first "for" has ended?

Comment: replace `5000` with `5000 + z * 1000` for example

Comment: @pskink may you explain why?

Comment: to have the `delayMillis` parameter values of 5000, 6000, 7000 and 8000 in four `postDelayed` method calls - thats why the first `Runnable` "runs" after 5 seconds, the second after 6 seconds and so on

Comment: @pskink thank you. Can you please see my updated question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here another aspect

```
private int z=0;
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(play.this, "z:" + z, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(z<4){
                  z++;
                  handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);
                }
            }
        }
handler.post(r);
```

Comment: Thanks, the catch was simply putting the second "for" under a 5 seconds delay before entering it.

Comment: you are welcome, I update asnwer. I use `handler.post` :)

Answer (score 0):

The handler runs your code on another thread, independent of your for loop. The delay is relative to the point where you posted the runnable. Not relative to the previous post. Also it doesn't block the for loop at all. That's the purpose of handlers.

You can assume that any post in this scenario happens at the same time, so you could just do `handler.postDelayed(runnable, (z + 1) * 5000)`. Or maybe define the execution time as absolute with `handler.postAtTime(runnable, firstRun + z * 5000)`

But since you're trying to do something more complicated than that, you should better consider using a [`Timer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) or similar. Maybe [`RxJava`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/).

Comment: @tynn handler.postDelayed(runnable, (z + 1) * 5000) actually works, but I didn't quite understand why? Why would 2*5000, 3*5000 etc work, and not 5000 all the time?

Comment: @tynn thanks, can you please see my updated question?

Comment: It's the same reason as before. The delay is relative to the time when you call `postDelayed()`. Not relative to the last posted runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code works like this:

- *hey handler, do it after 5s,*
- *oh and do it after 5s too,*
- *and do it after 5s too,*
- *and this plz do after 5s.*

Then we wait 5s and handler is doing those actions in one moment.

What you can do is change it to:

- *hey handler, do it after 5s,*
- *oh and do it after 10s,*
- *and this after 15s*
- *...*

Or you can do it like this:

- *hey handler do **it** after 5s, where '**it**' action is 'hey handler do it after 5s'.*

Then handler will wait 5s and call action 'hey handler do it after 5s'. So handler will have to wait again 5s and do some action after that time.

Here is code for my aproach:

```
final int finalZ = z;
delayedAction(handler, 0, z);
. . .
void delayedAction(final Handler handler, final int i, final int max) {
    if(i<max) {
        Toast.makeText(play.this, "z:" + finalZ, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                     delayedAction(handler, i+1, max);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm pretty sure I'll use this in the future but in my code I did something simpler this time :). But other than that you really helped me understand how the delay works, thank you for that.